# Failed to extract specific value from map object terraform

Tags: terraform

This is my main file

```
services_list = flatten([
  reverse(values(var.host_svc)) ])
 
}
variable "host_svc" {
  type = map(map(any))
  
}
output "aa" {
  value = local.services_list
}
```

This is terraform tfvars file

```
 host_svc = {
  accounts = {
    name = "accounts"
    pod = "3"
    cpu = "512M"
    memory = "1024M"
}
  analytics = {
    name = "analytics"
    pod = "3"
    cpu = "512M"
    memory = "1024M"
  }
}
```

When i am output local.services_list i ma getting whole object. i just want to fetch just name of each map object like accounts,analytics.

i have tried with list data type it works but i want to do with map ojject because i have to use different object values

Answer (score 1):

You can do that much easier than you are trying:

```
local {
  services_list = [for k, v in var.host_svc : k]
}
```

Or even more easy using the built-in `keys` function [1]:

```
local {
  services_list = keys(var.host_svc)
}
```

---

[1] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/keys

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you want to read the names from your map. If you want to read your map keys, just use [`keys(map)`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/keys) function:

```
variable "host_svc" {
  type = map(map(any))
  default = {
    accounts_k = {
      name   = "accounts"
      pod    = "3"
      cpu    = "512M"
      memory = "1024M"
    }
    analytics_k = {
      name   = "analytics"
      pod    = "3"
      cpu    = "512M"
      memory = "1024M"
    }
  }

}
output "aa" {
  value = keys(var.host_svc)
}
```

Which will output:

```
  + aa = [
      + "accounts_k",
      + "analytics_k",
    ]
```

*I used `_k` suffix just to differentiate between the map keys and your `name` key inside the internal map*

---

In case you want to read `name` attribute of that map you can do:

```
output "aa" {
  value = [for svc in local.services_list : svc.name]
}
```

In case you don't want to have duplicates in that outputted list, use [`toset()`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/toset):

```
output "aa" {
  value = toset([for svc in local.services_list : svc.name])
}
```